# When trying to Create a New Azure Key Vault using Azure Active Directory Module for Windows Powershell, it always failed

Tags: powershell, azure, entra-id

When trying to Create a New Azure Key Vault using Azure Active Directory Module for Windows Powershell, it always failed.
This is what I tried:

New-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName 'Contoso03Vault' -ResourceGroupName 'OMSTest' -Location 'East US'

WARNING: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Services.Client, Version=5.6.4.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
New-AzureRmKeyVault : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Services.Client, Version=5.6.4.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file
specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName 'Contoso03Vault' -ResourceGroupName 'O ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmKeyVault], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.NewAzureKeyVault

Any ideas on this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error log, it seems that you don't use latest Azure Power Shell. You could use following command to get your Azure Power shell version.

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh
```

The latest version is 4.4.1. You could download the installer file from the [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases) and install it.

Note: Cmdlet [`New-AzureRmKeyVault`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.keyvault/new-azurermkeyvault?view=azurermps-4.4.1) is a Azure Power Shell cmdlet not Azure AD Power Shell cmdlet. You should use the   cmdlet in Power Shell console not Azure AD Power shell console.

[image]